# Puppet Dashboard giving "The environment must be purely alphanumeric" error under Passenger

Tags: apache-2.2, puppet, phusion-passenger, puppetmaster, puppet-dashboard

Please refer to this [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/76182b847e1942046c84) for the `puppetmaster.conf` and `dashboard-vhost.conf` files.

I have my Puppetmaster (3.7.3) running on CentOS 6.5 under Apache and Passenger on port TCP/8140. It works fine. But my Puppet dashboard, also running under Passenger on port 80, yields this error when I browse to the server IP/hostname on port 80:

`The environment must be purely alphanumeric, not ''`

If I remove the `puppetmaster.conf` file from `/etc/httpd/conf.d`, I can browse to the dashboard. When I put it back, I get the error.

I've researched this and everything I've found shows this error in the context of someone browsing to the Puppetmaster on port 8140, even though I am browsing to port 80. I get the feeling I'm looking in the wrong place.

Comment: A word of warning - the Puppet folks are [trying quite hard to deprecate dashboard](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/puppet-dev/j44EbTJY7HI).. It hasn't received any official work in quite some time now. You may want to think about an alternative solution, such as [Puppetboard](https://github.com/puppet-community/puppetboard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have server-scoped settings in the top of each of those files, when they should only apply to the virtual host that they're relevant to.

Specifically, you'll need to move `PassengerAppRoot /usr/share/puppet/rack/puppetmasterd` into the `<VirtualHost *:8140>` block, as right now it's applying to the dashboard service as well.